# start-stop-daemon: command not found error in Debian

Tags: linux, debian, daemon

I'm a linux noob and I'm moving first steps on debian. I'm trying to execute a simple python script as a service, and I tried to execute this code (copied from the web) in order to do this.

```
DIR=/usr/local/bin/myservice
DAEMON=$DIR/myservice.py
DAEMON_NAME=myservice

# Add any command line options for your daemon here
DAEMON_OPTS=""

# This next line determines what user the script runs as.
# Root generally not recommended but necessary if you are using the Raspberry Pi GPIO from Python.
DAEMON_USER=root

# The process ID of the script when it runs is stored here:
PIDFILE=/var/run/$DAEMON_NAME.pid

. /lib/lsb/init-functions

do_start () {
    log_daemon_msg "Starting system $DAEMON_NAME daemon"
    start-stop-daemon --start --background --pidfile $PIDFILE --make-pidfile --user $DAEMON_USER --chuid $DAEMON_USER --startas $DAEMON -- $DAEMON_OPTS
    log_end_msg $?
}
do_stop () {
    log_daemon_msg "Stopping system $DAEMON_NAME daemon"
    start-stop-daemon --stop --pidfile $PIDFILE --retry 10
    log_end_msg $?
}

case "$1" in

    start|stop)
        do_${1}
        ;;

    restart|reload|force-reload)
        do_stop
        do_start
        ;;

    status)
        status_of_proc "$DAEMON_NAME" "$DAEMON" && exit 0 || exit $?
        ;;

    *)
        echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/$DAEMON_NAME {start|stop|restart|status}"
        exit 1
        ;;

esac
exit 0
```

anyway when I try to launch the init script he says:

```
bash: start-stop-daemon: command not found
```

so I tried to locate it using which command but I had no results. Also it isn't in /usr/bin either. What am I missing? I'm working on Debian 10 (fresh install on virtualbox)

Comment: It's in `/sbin`. Is that in your path?

Comment: yes, it is. Anyway even if I change dir to /sbin and try to execute start-stop-daemon command I get the same error.

Comment: `/sbin` is in the root's `PATH` but not in a regular user's `PATH`. `which` uses `PATH`, so it won't find the tool while invoked as regular user. `whereis start-stop-daemon` can find it though. After you `cd` to `/sbin`, plain `start-stop-daemon` still requires `/sbin` to be in your `PATH`. To run `start-stop-daemon` from the current working directory you need to invoke it like this: `./start-stop-daemon`. All symptoms will make sense if it turns out you tried to execute the script as regular user. So how *exactly* and from what account did you try to execute the script?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this issue when building an Ubuntu live image using `live-build`.

In my case, `start-stop-daemon` had **somehow gotten deleted or corrupted**, and this meant neither `apt` nor `apt-get` were usable.

It also turns out that `dpkg` similarly doesn't play nicely when it's missing.

The program comes from the `dpkg` package, which is the underlying tool that `apt` uses to install `.deb` files. So I browsed around archive.ubuntu.com for Ubuntu Focal and found the exact same dpkg version that was already installed, thus I could install it without any library conflicts.

Dpkg's package files are stored here on the official Ubuntu repo: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/d/dpkg/

Check your existing dpkg's version using:

```
apt show dpkg
```

Next, download the `.deb` file for dpkg, make sure to get the same version and architecture (e.g. 1.9.7_amd64), or if that's not available, a version very close by (e.g. 1.9.9).

```
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/d/dpkg/dpkg_1.19.7ubuntu3_amd64.deb
```

Since `dpkg` depends on start-stop-daemon to actually install itself, **we need to make a dummy binary that won't conflict** with the new one that gets installed. The dummy binary will simply return 0 (success), and nothing more.

Put it in `/usr/bin/` or `/bin/` - but NOT `/sbin/` or `/usr/sbin/`. The real executable will be installed at `/sbin` or `/usr/sbin`.

```
# We use the very simple program /bin/true as the shebang, so that
# start-stop-daemon simply returns 0 (success) when ran.
echo '#!/bin/true' > /usr/bin/start-stop-daemon
# Make the file executable
chmod +x /usr/bin/start-stop-daemon
```

Now, we should be able to reinstall `dpkg` which should reinstall `start-stop-daemon`:

```
dpkg -i dpkg_1.19.7ubuntu3_amd64.deb
```

Assuming it installs successfully, you'll now want to remove the dummy executable, to avoid it being preferred over the real one:

```
rm -f /usr/bin/start-stop-daemon
```

You should now be good to go :)

**NOTE**: If you use `zsh` then you should make sure to run `rehash` now, to update it's cache of binary locations.

Answer (score 2):

You might have to set root's PATH first though. Edit `/root/.bashrc` (with root privileges of course), and add the following line and save:

`export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin`

Then source the file wherever you want to execute: `# source /root/.bashrc`

Then run you dpkg: `# dpkg -i file.deb`